# Minium distance between two strings

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given 2 strings **A**,**B**. We can insert some characters '**-**' in to them.

Example: X="**abedf**", we can insert -> "**a-b--edf-**" or "**ab-e-df**" ...

We call distance of A and B is **abs(ASCII(A[i]-ASCII(B[i]))**. But if A[i] or B[i] is '-', the value will be **K**.
And we have to find the minium distance of them.

***Example:***

A="**cmc**"

B="**scmn**"

K=**2**

We can insert to

A : "**-c-m-c**"

B : "**s-nmn-**"

so the distance is **10**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Let A,B to be the given strings.*

Note that at most, we will insert '-' as much as to make the two strings not touching each other:

```
 d("cmc","scmn")<= d("cmc----","---scmn") =7*2=14
```

Also note that inserting `"-" over "-"` (the first is in A, the second is in B) is useless as its just increase the distance by `2`

Also, let `d(i,j)` to be `ABS(ASCI(A[i]-B[j]))` if these operation is legal, and o.w `d(i,j) = 2` (because `i>len(A) or j>len(B)`)

Now,let `c(i,k)` to be the min distance of A[:i] and B[:j]

**We will look after `c(2\*max(len(A),len(B)),2*max(len(A),len(B)))`.**

Note that `c(0,0)=0`.

The general case is:

```
c(i,k) =min of these cases:

 - d(i,k) + c(i+1,k+1)
 - 2 + c(i+1,k)
 - 2 + c(i,k+1)
```